# Scala MongoDB, override codec to write/read Array[Byte]

Tags: mongodb, scala, nosql

I am using http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-scala-driver/

I am defining codec for one CC.

```
 lazy val userInfoCodec: Codec[UserInfo] = new Codec[UserInfo] {

    override def encode(writer: BsonWriter, value: UserInfo, encoderContext: EncoderContext): Unit = ???
    override def decode(reader: BsonReader, decoderContext: DecoderContext): UserInfo = ???
}
```

Inside I am doing encryption, so fields instead of being Strings are Array[Byte].
Do you know how to use BsonWriter to write bytes array there ?
I saw some stuff like writeStartArray, but I dont get how to use it.

Thanks for help!

Comment: I don't think you need to write a real **BSON** `Array`, but instead you may give a look to the [`BsonBinary` _type_](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.9/javadoc/org/bson/BsonBinary.html) which takes a `byte[]` as its data argument. _(the `BsonWriter` API exposes a method for writing `BinaryData`)_. - Other option would be to encode the `byte[]` as a **Base64** `String` after doing the encryption.

Answer (score 3):

```
case class UserInfo(ab: Array[Byte])

val userInfoCodec: Codec[UserInfo] = new Codec[UserInfo] {
  override def getEncoderClass: Class[UserInfo] = classOf[UserInfo]

  override def encode(writer: BsonWriter, value: UserInfo, encoderContext: EncoderContext): Unit = {
    val bsonBinary = new BsonBinary(value.ab)
    writer.writeBinaryData(bsonBinary)
  }



  override def decode(reader: BsonReader, decoderContext: DecoderContext): UserInfo = {
    val bsonBinary = reader.readBinaryData()
    UserInfo(bsonBinary.getData)
  }
}
```